# How use Button in ScrollView in NGUI to scroll the object

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, ngui

I made the Scrollable View in NGUI using following tutorials [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiA4o8KqBFI) but how can I use button to scroll the objects. Like If i click on up button it ScrollView should be up and If i click on down ScrollView should be down.

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two different things to have scrolling button, depending what do you mean.

1. If you want to have a scroll button, you should create `UIScrollBar` component, which you will attach to you `UIScrollView` as a horizontal or vertical scroll bar. See NGUI examples included to the package.
2. If you want to have a object on your list, which clicked will allow you to drag the `UIScrollView`, you should attach to this gameObject a `UIDragScrollView` component. It will allow you to drag-to-scroll behavior, similar to mobile list dragging experience. Again, such example should be included to the package.

EDIT: After your question clarification, the answer should be a bit different.

You should write a script, with a reference to your `UIScrollView` and then you should call on it [MoveRelative( Vector3 relative )](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_scroll_view.html#a9c4022868f0d42e841b973a1e58103ad) or [MoveAbsolute( Vector3 absolute )](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_scroll_view.html#af874815821a671411b15c09e2b498ca4), which will move the scroll view.

Comment: actually i want a arrow button up and down. when i click on up button is should go up and if i click on down button it should go down like such functionality.

Comment: Ok, so you should clarify your question, to be precise about what are you asking.

Comment: ok i will always clarify my question. actually i am little bit in rush.

Comment: How it should move smoothly. Because code i have written is reaching to target position directly.

Comment: You can implement your own `Tween` - inherit from base class `UITweener` and on OnUpdate call one of the `Move` functions with actual delta time (there should be small move values). Then on button you should start your tween. See `UITweener` reference: http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_tweener.html#a079f453157c77ba20ad43cfb10683187

Comment: Hey there, can you give in the additional details on HOW EXACTLY did you achieve this in NGUI?

Answer (score 3):

I just figure out how to do this.

```
SpringPanel.Begin ( GameObject go,Vector3 pos,float strength )
```

here GameObject is NGUI gameObject such as ScrollView and pos is position what amount should scrollview move and strength is that related to speed. hope you will find useful.

Comment: Hey there, can you give in the additional details on HOW EXACTLY did you achieve this in NGUI? Because this seems like a static method and how is spring panel refereed and in which script. Please provide addition details. Thanks

Comment: `Begin` is a `SpringPanel` static method, see reference [here](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_spring_panel.html).

Comment: Hi @user1683989 i just explain about spring.panel hope it is useful for you.